# Simplifying $(6a-b)(36a^2+6ab+b^2)+(3a+b)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would really appreciate some help with simplifying this algebraic problem.

> $(6a-b)(36a^2+6ab+b^2)+(3a+b)^3$

This part seems a bit tricky: $(36a^2+6ab+b^2)$

Shouldn't it be $12ab$ in the middle? That way, it would be possible to solve it using $(a+b)^2$

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint:

$$x^{3} - y^{3} = (x-y)(x^{2} + xy + y^{2})$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simplify:**$(6a-b)(36a^2+6ab+b^2)=(6a)^3-b^3$

Comment: My final answer, using this was $3a(11a^2+9ab+3b^2)$
Is this right, then?

Comment: The final answer should be: $3a(81a^2+9ab+3b^2)$.

Comment: $6a^3 - b^3 + (3a+b)^3$ </br>
$6a^3 -b^3 + (27a^3 + b^3 + 27a^b + 9ab^2)$  </br>
$6a^3 - b^3 + 27a^3 + b^3 + 27a^2b + 9ab^2$  </br>
$33a^3 + 27a^b + 9ab^2$  </br>
$= 3a(11a^3 + 9ab + 3b^2)$

Comment: I cannot find a way to add linebreaks, so please excuse the formatting.

Comment: It's: ($6a)^3-b^3+(3a+b)^3=216a^3-b^3+27a^3+27a^2b+9ab^2+b^3$. Eventually this is equal to: $243a^3+27a^2b+9ab^2$

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized my mistake. Utterly stupid of me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$(6a-b)(36a^2+6ab+b^2)=(6a)^3-(b)^3$$

---

so:

$$
(6a-b)(36a^2+6ab+b^2)+(3a+b)^3=(6a)^3-b^3+3^3a^3+3\cdot3^2a^2b+3\cdot3ab^2+b^3=
$$
$$
=2^3\cdot3^3a^3+3^3a^3+3\cdot3^2a^2b+3\cdot3ab^2=3^3a^3(8+1)+3\cdot3^2a^2b+3\cdot3ab^2=
$$
$$
=3^5a^3+3^3a^2b+3^2ab^2=3^2a(3^3a^2+3ab+b^2)
$$

Comment: Using this, final answer I got was $3a(11a^2+9ab+3b^2)$
Is this right?

Comment: Sorry. I had a stupid mistake...I edit.

Comment: Its fine :) But if you could check my answer, that would be great!

Comment: Your $11 a^2$ is wrong. See the comment of Paulo.

Comment: @AmanBhargava See my answer how to test your calculation, without the help of others.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Why did you take $a=1$ and $b=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to check your calculation. You got $f(a,b)=3a(11a^2+9ab+3b^2)$.
Hence $f(1,0)=33$. Now check in your given formula for $a=1$ and $b=0$. Then you' ll obtain $f(1,0)=243$, a contradiction. So your calculation cannot be correct. Indeed, we have
$$
f(a,b)=9a(27a^2 + 3ab + b^2).
$$